# The name 'EVAL' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a button in the header of the grid view but Visual Studio highlights this asn an error:

> 'The name EVAL does not exist in the current context'.

Why does this happen, and how can it be solved?

```
 <asp:gridview  runat="server" >    
      <Columns>
         .....
         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litFamily" Text='<%# EVAL("CompanyAddress") %>'></asp:Literal>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
         .....
```

Comment: Use like Text='<%# Eval("CompanyAddress") %>'

Answer (score 5):

Use either

1. `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CompanyAddress")%>`
2. `<%# Eval("CompanyAddress") %>`

Comment: Both of these work, I'm just curious why the word Eval is still flagged red as an error in Visual Studio in the 2nd one even though it works if you run it.

Answer (score 4):

Use '**Eval**' (E -> capital letter, val  > small letters) in place of '**EVAL**' (all capital letters)